# Pre-Create user as admin with NextAuth (like an Invite Email)

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'm using prisma with NextAuth on a Nextjs13 project.
I already know how to disable SignUp: I'm looking in User table to see if email exists, and if not, I return false in signin calback.
Now that sign up is disabled, I would like to be able to create User as an admin. So I've tried those two solutions:

1. Create manually a user with API, but then the user isn't able to log in because he doesn't have anything in the Account table. The error message is:

   `To confirm your identity, sign in with the same account you used originally.`
2. Use EmailProvider to send an Invite Email to user. The problem is the following one:

```
    model User {
      id            String    @id @default(cuid())
      name          String?
      email         String?   @unique
      emailVerified DateTime?
      image         String?
      clientId      String
      accounts      Account[]
      sessions      Session[]
      client        Client    @relation(fields: [clientId], references: [id])
      role          EnumRole  @default(manager)
    }
```

As you can see, my user model has extended properties (clientId, role), so when the user click on the link in his email, I have this error:

`Argument client for data.client is missing.`

and the user isn't created.

How could I do without having to duplicate email in an other table? I don't want to have an 'AllowedEmail' table, it would add complexity and duplicate my data.